# unique functional

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm trying to see why this statement is true:

If $\|u\|_p=1$ then considering:
\begin{align}
 \xi_u:L^p(\Omega,\mathbb{C})&\to \mathbb{C}\\
<\xi_u,v>&:=\int_{\Omega}\overline{u}|u|^{p-2}vdx, \ \forall v\in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb{C})
\end{align}

Then $\xi_u$ has the properties $\|\xi_u\|_p=\|u\|_p=\xi_u(u)=1$. This is ok to me.
The statement is: $\xi_u$ is the unique functional with the properties above. It must be because $L^p$ is uniformely convex but I can't see why.

Comment: If $\xi'$ is another candidate and $\xi_{u} \neq \xi'$, notice that $\frac{1}{2}(\xi' + \xi_{u})$ evaluates to $1$ on $u$ so its (operator) norm is at least $1$.  This is incompatible with uniform convexity.

Comment: OHH yess! Thank you I got it